# Rxjava, how can I repeat after onComplete or onError

Tags: rx-java

I have a code block may like this.

```
fun main() {
    foo()
            .flatMap {
                bar()
            }
            .subscribe({}, {
                main()
            },{
                main()
            })
}

fun foo(): Observable<Int> {
    // has some real business which take times here
    return Observable.just(1)
}

fun bar(): Observable<Int> {
    // has some real business which take times here
    return Observable.just(2)
}
```

Which will repeat after onComplete or onError.

But I think the style above is not good! Is any good way to this in RxJava itself?

Comment: What's wrong with `retry()` and `repeat()`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake to `repeat`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply `retry` and `repeat`:

```
foo()
.flatMap {
     bar()
}
.retry()           // <------------------------------------------
.repeat()
.subscribe({}, {
    // never fails
},{
    // never ends
})
```